# How can I call Scala function with class name and function name as strings

Tags: scala

I have to write scheduler that callbacks a function after processing. I can register the class name and method name as strings and have to callback it in future.

How can I call a function with class name and method name in Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same with java, use reflect.

```
package tst

class A {
  def fun(a:String) = print(a)
}

object B extends App {
  val classA = Class.forName("tst.A")
  val method = classA.getDeclaredMethod("fun", classOf[String])
  method.invoke(classA.newInstance(), "hello world")
}
```